# How to add attributes to parent dom elements of component in angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom-manipulation

I have the following:

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div class="fancy">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addAttribute()">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="remAttribute()">Add</button>
</div>
```

...
My question is, How can I make it so that when the user hits "addAttribute()" it adds "testattribute" to the parent dom element of the component like this:

```
  <div class="fancy" testattribute="a">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
```

This is my fancy-button component, below is the parent template that i have the fancy-button integrated in within the home.component.html:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fancy-button',
  template: `<button>clickme</button>`
})
export class FancyButton {}

@Component({
  selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
```

Comment: You could use *ngIf in order to hide the test button, then set the test button to a function that is called when you hit your addAtrribute button. similar to a show/hide effect

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. Why do you want to add a "testattribute" to the div? What's your end goal? And how is the fancybutton relevant to the question?

Comment: I have attributes in there for absolute positioning: top: 40px, left: 50px. I my goal is to make it so that I can click I button to change the absolute position of the container that has fancybutton in it, but is implemented inside of the fancybutton component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fancy" [attr.testattribute]="isAttr">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
  <button (click)="isAttr = true">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="isAttr = false">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution (untested at time of writing):

Add the name and value of the parameters to the `addAttribute()`call as follows:

```
addAttribute("testattribute", "a");
```

You'll also need to add `this.parentElement` to the beginning of the call:

```
this.parentElement.addAttribute("testattribute", a");
```

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Where is the reference to "this" coming from inside of the component? this.parentElement is undefined.

Comment: Does not work. Not sure where referennce to "this" comes from.